# Read data from Socket on JavaScript/HTML page

Tags: javascript, sockets

I have SocketServer on Java with opened Socket and data, that sends on telnet-like way: when I open this socket in Chrome (localhost:9999 e.g.) some events repeatedly displayed.

So the question is: how can I parse this data using JS on single html page? I want to add some charts after parsing this data.

I've tryed to use WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999") but get only "invalid status line" error on WebSocket handshake.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

UPD: This is an example of implementation of my SocketServer on Java: (no special code for WebSocket)

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(9999);
            Socket sock = ssock.accept();
            ssock.close();

            PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
                pstream.println(i);
            }
            pstream.close();
            sock.close();
        }
    }
```

I need to trace this PrintStream on a webpage using JS.

Comment: can you try using `ws://127.0.0.1:9999` ? `SocketServer` has a WebSocket implementation ? Socket != WebSocket

Comment: yeah. the same result...

Comment: Did you follow the [WebSocket rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) to implement your server?

Comment: no, SocketServer have no specific WebSocket implementation.
another question then: browser can "imitate" telnet client, can I use this ability in my JS code on a page?

Comment: It might help to read up on the javax.websocket spec. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html

An alternative to this would be Netty http://netty.io/ which is a very efficient library for writing socket servers and has support for websockets. The issue with this approach though is if you are using something that requires session context (Such as a Tomcat Session) from the header, then Netty might give you problems since it uses a custom request object.

For the front-end, I recommend going with something like socket.io or sockJS.